# Is this generally a necessary condition for Orthogonality of a finite set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1,...,v_n$ be indexed vectors in an inner product space $V$ such that $i\neq j\Rightarrow \langle v_i,v_j\rangle = 0$

In some texts, the condition "$i\neq j \Rightarrow v_i\neq v_j$" is necessary for $\{v_1,..,v_n\}$ to be an orthogonal set.

However, in some other texts the above condition is not necessary and $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is an orthogonal set itself.

I think the latter one is more natural than the former one in the case index set is explicitly stated.

Which one is right?

Comment: As Alfonso points out below me, nonzero vectors may yield a zero norm over the right field and inner product. Regardless, in my experience, you don't bother putting the multiple vectors into an orthogonal set. Generally you're going to take the span of it or use it to make an orthonormal basis or something similar and duplicates get thrown out.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\left<(1,1), (1,1)\right>=0$ (with $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ the standard inner product).

Comment: @Alfonso You're quite right. I've amended my comment.

Comment: @Katlus That condition is usually required for a collection to be a set, so it's implicit wherever $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is said to be a set.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. But (1)indexing on a set and (2)to be given an indexed set are different. Mostly, we take indexing on a given set ourselves so $i\neq j\Rightarrow v_i\neq v_j$. However, sometimes if these indexed sets are given, confusion arises.

Comment: So should i take the latter one as the definition of an orthogonal set when the set is given indexed?